# Env variables not persisting in parent shell

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I have the following bash script that attempts to automate the assuming of an AWS role (I've obviously removed the various private settings):

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Dependencies:
#   brew install jq
#
# Execute:
#   source aws-cli-assumerole.sh

unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<user_access_key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<user_secret_key>

temp_role=$(aws sts assume-role \
                    --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<aws_account_number>:role/<role_name>" \
                    --role-session-name "<some_session_name>")

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.AccessKeyId)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.SecretAccessKey)
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.SessionToken)

env | grep -i AWS_
```

I have to execute this script using `source` because otherwise if I use standard `bash` or `sh` the exported environment variables are not available within the parent shell executing this script.

The problem is, even when using `source` it doesn't work; and by that I mean: the environment variables AND their correct/updated values are showing in the parent shell (if I execute `env | grep AWS_` I can see the correct values).

If I then try to use the AWS CLI tools (e.g. `aws s3 ls` - to list all s3 buckets within the specific account I've assumed the role for) it'll report back that the access key is invalid.

BUT, if I manually copy and paste the environment variable values and re-export them in the parent shell (effectively overwriting them with the exact same values that are already set), *then* the AWS CLI command will work - but I do not know why. What's different?

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings?

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't. I'm running on a Mac (Unix system)

Comment: Not able to reproduce this on OSX 10.11.4 with bash-3.2 or bash-4.3 with aws-cli/1.10.21

Comment: @Integralist have you found solution for that? I am experiencing same thing on OSX 10.12.1

Comment: @Daemeron I ended up piping to xargs (can't remember the logic/reasoning now), but see a working example here: https://github.com/Integralist/Shell-Scripts/blob/master/aws-cli-assumerole.sh

Comment: Have you tried executing your script using the `.` operator instead of using `source`?  I know they're supposed to be the same thing, but I'm just wondering if maybe the `source` command is not correctly referencing the `.` command??  Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 1):

`jq .Blah` will return the output quoted.

So for example
`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $temp_role | jq .Credentials.AccessKeyId)`
Will result `"KEY"` instead what you need is just `KEY` which is why your xargs works in your comment.

If you use the -r flag for raw with jq you will get the result you want
`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $temp_role | jq -r .Credentials.AccessKeyId)`

Comment: Adding -r to the jq commands indeed fixes the issue with the original posters' script. The entire issue is that the access key/token/id are enclosed in quotes. The AWS CLI then returns an error that the token is invalid. (And, thank you for this script OP, I found this post because I needed this script and knew someone else had written it already!)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to assume an AWS role:

Write a profile, which automatically assumes the role.

```
aws configure --profile new-profile set arn:aws:iam::<aws_account_number>:role/<role_name>
```

To give credentials to the new profile, you must use one of the following lines:

1. `aws configure --profile new-profile set source_profile default`
2. `aws configure --profile new-profile set credential_sourceEc2InstanceMetadata`
3. `aws configure --profile new-profile set credential_source EcsContainer`

Line 1 was correct on my personal pc, because I used the default profile.
Line 3 was correct when I tested the code with AWS CodeBuild. The new profile used the credentials of the codepipeline-role.

Afterwards, you may use the new profile, example:
`aws --profile new-profile s3 ls s3://bucket-in-target-account`

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#using-aws-iam-roles